# PHP - how to extract text from image using Google Cloud Vision

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform

```
namespace Google\Cloud\Samples\Vision;    

require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

    use Google\Cloud\Vision\VisionClient;

    $vision = new VisionClient([
        'projectId' => 'xxx',
        'keyFilePath' => 'xxx.json'
    ]);




    use Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient;


    function detect_text($path)
    {
        $imageAnnotator = new ImageAnnotatorClient();

        # annotate the image
        $image = file_get_contents($path);
        $response = $imageAnnotator->textDetection($image);
        $texts = $response->getTextAnnotations();

        printf('%d texts found:' . PHP_EOL, count($texts));
        foreach ($texts as $text) {
            print($text->getDescription() . PHP_EOL);

            # get bounds
            $vertices = $text->getBoundingPoly()->getVertices();
            $bounds = [];
            foreach ($vertices as $vertex) {
                $bounds[] = sprintf('(%d,%d)', $vertex->getX(), $vertex->getY());
            }
            print('Bounds: ' . join(', ',$bounds) . PHP_EOL);
        }

        $imageAnnotator->close();
    }

    echo detect_text('read.png');
```

Installed the SDK and PHP Package and I'm getting error 500 no matter what I do!

How can I get this running?

This is the error I get:

```
[01-Feb-2020 19:09:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\gcloud/application_default_credentials.json) is not within the allowed path(s): (C:/Inetpub/vhosts/xxxxxxx.com\;C:\Windows\Temp\) in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\xxxxxxx.com\vendor\google\auth\src\CredentialsLoader.php on line 100
[01-Feb-2020 19:09:50 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught DomainException: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\xxxxxxx.com\vendor\google\auth\src\ApplicationDefaultCredentials.php:168
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\xxxxxxx.com\vendor\google\gax\src\CredentialsWrapper.php(197): Google\Auth\ApplicationDefaultCredentials::getCredentials(Array, Object(Google\Auth\HttpHandler\Guzzle6HttpHandler), NULL, NULL)
#1 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\xxxxxxx.com\vendor\google\gax\src\CredentialsWrapper.php(114): Google\ApiCore\CredentialsWrapper::buildApplicationDefaultCredentials(Array, Object(Google\Auth\HttpHandler\Guzzle6HttpHandler))
#2 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\xxxxxxx.com\vendor\google\gax\src\GapicClientTrait.php(339): Google\ApiCore\CredentialsWrapper::build(Array)
#3 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\xxxxxxx.com\vendor\google\gax\src\GapicClientTrait.php(321): Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\Gapic\ImageAnnotatorGapicClient->createCredentialsWrapper(NULL, in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\xxxxxxx.com\vendor\google\gax\src\CredentialsWrapper.php on line 200
```

I have done everything exactly how their documentation said to: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/setup what am I suppose to do now?

Comment: Please turn on `display_errors` and show us what the error is that you're getting from the server. It's hard to answer a question without all of the information.

Comment: You say that you keep getting error 500. have you checked the servers error log for the actual error message?

Comment: So you've just updated your question to include more completely unexplained code. There's also no hint on how the code in the different namespaces are related. We're not asking for more code, we're asking for a proper explanation of your issue (including any error message you get)

Comment: I have updated the question with error log

Comment: Based on the error message you receive, it looks like the credentials file is at wrong place (Inside C:\Windows\System32, which is not in the list of allowed paths. Why is that credentials file under System32 anyway?).

Comment: The file is in C:/key.json and not C:\Windows\System32 and I also declared it there! what the hell is wrong with this awful google software??? Now I changed it to 'keyFilePath' => 'C:/Inetpub/vhosts/xxxx.com/key.json' and get: PHP Warning:  file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\gcloud/application_default_credentials.json) is not within the allowed path(s): (C:/Inetpub/vhosts/xxxx.com\;C:\Windows\Temp\) in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\xxxx.com\vendor\google\auth\src\CredentialsLoader.php on line 100

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the google vision client. The problem is PHP cannot open the credentials file in the location you’ve placed it. Figure out why that is the case. Start by searching for the error message. “open_basedir restriction in effect”

Comment: @jdp I did and can't find anything useful. Why can't PHP open the json file when it's in the same place as other website files/images which PHP can open?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it by using the key.json inside the SDK folder and also inside the PHP script, so two times.

And the example codes in the official google cloud documentation are completely worthless and are still giving 500 error even with SDK and PHP package correctly intialized.

I found a working code on github which I slightly modified:

```
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

use Google\Cloud\Vision\VisionClient;

$vision = new VisionClient([
    'projectId' => 'xxxx',
    'keyFilePath' => 'key.json'
]);

// Annotate an image, detecting faces.
$image = $vision->image(
    fopen('read.png', 'r'),
    ['text']
);

$tadaa = $vision->annotate($image);


echo '<pre>';
var_dump($tadaa->text());
echo '</pre>';
```

Now after many hours of struggle it finally WORKS!